# ElectronJS: How Rotate an Image in Electron?

Tags: electron

I see that [nativeImage](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/native-image.md) allows for some resizing and other manipulation, but I need to give the user the ability to rotate an image 90 degrees. Is this possible with an Electron application?

Answer (score 0):

A `nativeImage` exposes `getBitmap`, you can use this to manipulate the raw pixel data.

Rotating an image is as simple as making moving each pixel of an array. Basically doing `yourBuffer[x][y] = yourBuffer[y][x]`

Answer (score 0):

With Electron you can use almost any node.js library in the [npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com). For example you could use [`imagejs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagejs) to rotate the bitmap.

Note: I haven't actually tested this:

```
const ImageJS = require("imagejs");

const buf = nativeImage.getBitmap();
const { width, height } = nativeImage.getSize();

const bitmap = new ImageJS.Bitmap({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    data: buf
});

const rotated = bitmap.rotate({degrees: 90, fit: "crop"});
```